# How to handle local-state in flutter with provider?

Tags: flutter, clean-architecture, state-management, flutter-state

I use the provider package to manage my application state. I have a few questions concerning how to manage the state in the application.

- Is it a good practice to create a ChangeNotifier class for each screen in my application to handle the back end for this page (which is provided to only this screen) ?

**In an example like this**:
If i have a page that have multiple widgets and i need to rebuild a small part of the page like adding a new TextField on enabling a switch.

in the previous example

- Should i use a provider to only rebuild the small part of the page or this part is mostly handled by only using changeState() ?

in case that the local-state of the page should be handled in the screen.

- Where should i place the logic of the page, like http requests on button clicks and loading data for this page ?

Answer (score 0):

If the state that you are updating is only needed within one widget with one or two down widgets down the tree, I would recommend using the built-in SetState. While both Provider and SetState would work for any form of state management, I tend to think of Provider as similar to [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

- Provider is great for holding state at page levels or if you want to maintain the separation between widget builds and logic in different files.
- SetState is great for local widgets with not a lot of nested widgets underneath.

Here is a great [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/flutter-state-management-in-2021-when-to-use-what-98722093b8bc) that discusses the different state management solution approaches. At the end of the day, it's up to preference!